# Getting an odd error when trying to make a heatmap with Seaborn library

Tags: python, seaborn, heatmap

I'm trying to make a Seaborn heatmap out of the data I got from Rotten Tomatoes with requests module with the code below:

```
print("initializing")
import requests
import re
import os
import time
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
def tomatoes(movie):
    request = requests.get("https://www.rottentomatoes.com/m/" + movie)
    soup = str(BeautifulSoup(request.text, "html.parser"))
    a_score = soup[soup.index("audiencescore="):soup.index("audiencestate")]
    t_score = soup[soup.index("tomatometerscore="):soup.index("tomatometerstate")]
    results = []
    for k in [t_score, a_score]:
        results.append("".join([i for i in [j for j in k] if i.isdigit()]))
    return results
def movies():
    YEARS_ADD = {"doctor_strange": "2016",
               "black_panther": "2018"}
    wiki_scrape_string = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Marvel_Cinematic_Universe_films"
    df = pd.read_html(wiki_scrape_string, header=0)[1]
    df.to_excel("table.xlsx")
    df = pd.ExcelFile("table.xlsx").parse("Sheet1")
    movies = [i for i in df["Film"].tolist() if "Phase" not in i]
    os.remove("table.xlsx")
    movies = [i.replace("'", "") for i in movies]
    movies = [re.sub("[^0-9a-zA-Z]+", "_", i).lower() for i in movies]
    movies_final = []
    for movie in movies:
        try:
            movies_final.append(movie + "_" + YEARS_ADD[movie])
        except KeyError:
            movies_final.append(movie)  
    return movies_final
def box_office():
    wiki_scrape_string = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Marvel_Cinematic_Universe_films"
    df = pd.read_html(wiki_scrape_string, header=0)[4]
    df.to_excel("table.xlsx")
    df = pd.ExcelFile("table.xlsx").parse("Sheet1")
    gross = df["Box office gross.2"].tolist()
    gross = [i for i in gross if all(j in "0123456789,$" for j in i)][:-1]
    for i in ["$", ","]:
        gross = [j.replace(i, "") for j in gross]
    gross = [int(i) for i in gross]
    return gross
print("collecting data")
t_scores = []
a_scores = []
count = 0
for i in movies():
    t_scores.append(tomatoes(i)[0])
    a_scores.append(tomatoes(i)[1])
    count += 1
    print(f"{count}/23 complete")
    time.sleep(0.5)
print("finalizing")
df = pd.DataFrame([t_scores, a_scores],
                  columns = movies(), index = ["TS", "AS"])
df.transpose()
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize = (15, 15))
sns.heatmap(df, cmap ='RdYlGn', linewidths = 0.30, annot = True)
plt.savefig("colormap_mcu.png")
```

However, I get this monstrosity of an error instead of a heatmap I want:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Gleb\Мои Папки\py\movie_reviews.py", line 63, in <module>
    sns.heatmap(df, cmap ='RdYlGn', linewidths = 0.30, annot = True)
  File "C:\Users\Gleb\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\seaborn\_decorators.py", line 46, in inner_f
    return f(**kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Gleb\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\seaborn\matrix.py", line 548, in heatmap
    plotter.plot(ax, cbar_ax, kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Gleb\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\seaborn\matrix.py", line 332, in plot
    ax.figure.draw(ax.figure.canvas.get_renderer())
  File "C:\Users\Gleb\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\artist.py", line 41, in draw_wrapper
    return draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Gleb\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\figure.py", line 1863, in draw
    mimage._draw_list_compositing_images(
  File "C:\Users\Gleb\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\image.py", line 131, in _draw_list_compositing_images
    a.draw(renderer)
  File "C:\Users\Gleb\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\artist.py", line 41, in draw_wrapper
    return draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Gleb\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\cbook\deprecation.py", line 411, in wrapper
    return func(*inner_args, **inner_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Gleb\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_base.py", line 2747, in draw
    mimage._draw_list_compositing_images(renderer, self, artists)
  File "C:\Users\Gleb\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\image.py", line 131, in _draw_list_compositing_images
    a.draw(renderer)
  File "C:\Users\Gleb\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\artist.py", line 41, in draw_wrapper
    return draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Gleb\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\collections.py", line 2024, in draw
    self.update_scalarmappable()
  File "C:\Users\Gleb\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\collections.py", line 855, in update_scalarmappable
    self._facecolors = self.to_rgba(self._A, self._alpha)
  File "C:\Users\Gleb\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\cm.py", line 332, in to_rgba
    x = self.norm(x)
  File "C:\Users\Gleb\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\colors.py", line 1061, in __call__
    resdat -= vmin
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'float'
```

Neither removing df.transpose() nor fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize = (15, 15)) helps, and I'm honestly kinda stuck on this.

Comment: The error seems to indicate that not all the columns of your dataframe are numeric. Also, note that `df.transpose()` has no effect in your code. You either need `df = df.transpose()` or call `sns.heatmap(df.transpose(), ...)`

Comment: Oh, thanks, I totally forgot that I stored the values as strings, thank you so much.